# FFMPEG commands isn't working in Android Q

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffprobe

Try this command for merge two audio files, but its not working in Android 10.0(Q) while **targeting sdk 29**.
But, this command is completely working on **targeting sdk 24 to 28**.

I am using this library of FFMPEG implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.7'

```
"-y", "-i", path1, "-i", path2, "-filter_complex", "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest", "-c:a", "libmp3lame", savedPath

my Error log:
2019-09-28 13:48:32.037 16041-16166/com.merger.cut E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [/data/user/0/com..merger.cut/files/ffmpeg, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Music/song1.mp3, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Music/song2.mp3, -filter_complex, [0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest, -c:a, libmp3lame, /storage/emulated/0/merger/Merge_1569658695254.mp3]
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.merger.cut/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:15)
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:43)
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:12)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:15) 
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:43) 
        at nl.bravobit.ffmpeg.FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFcommandExecuteAsyncTask.java:12) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2019-09-28 13:48:32.146 16041-16041/com.merger.cut E/FFMPEG :: on finish
```

Give me solution for above problem.

Comment: get the same issue if anyone have solution please help

Comment: you may be affected by the new managed scoped access https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: Are you using this library : nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.1 or other please mention hear.

Comment: any error log? post your ffmpeg error log here

Comment: find any solution if yes please share your ans with us Thank You!

Comment: I have published a [fix](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/pull/130), but it will not resolve all problems on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: @HardikVasani try below answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now If You Guys Looking For FFMPEG for ANDROID Q Here is link use below FFMPEG Build. Include this to your **app/build.gradle**

**Min SDK 24**

```
  dependencies {
        implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.3'
    }
```

**Min SDK 16**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2.LTS'
}
```

tested in **OnePlus 7T**
**Android Q**

Comment: library size is too large.

Comment: @TusharLathiya You can you aab File for apk .

Comment: Currently, we don't have alternative for this.

Comment: instead of `-full`, you can use one of the [smaller packages](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/wiki/Packages)

Comment: I'm using 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2.LTS' But I get this error in build time ' Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx) from AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-47
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.3.2] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-26:19 to override.'

Comment: tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" add this lien to manifest file.in application tag

Answer (score 0):

For this library is only support maximum sdk 28 see the below link:

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/blob/master/android-ffmpeg/build.gradle

So,In this library not run in SDK 29 because the `targetSdkVersion 28` and  `compileSdkVersion 28` . If you want to change this thing, it'll work for you. I hope it will help you..!

Comment: I already tried it but it's not working when target to 29 and i want in 29.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead [link](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android)

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-video:5.1.LTS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this library

implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'

It works great. If there is any doubt please let me know. Thanks

This is how i have used it

```
private class CompressVideo extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    String oldPath;
    File newFile;
    int videoLength;

    CompressVideo(String oldPath, File newFile, int VideoLength) {
        this.newFile = newFile;
        this.oldPath = oldPath;
        this.videoLength = VideoLength;
        rvProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvProgressPercentage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Config.enableStatisticsCallback(statistics -> {
            runOnUiThread(() -> tvProgressPercentage.setText((statistics.getTime() * 100) / videoLength + "%"));
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setClickable(rlMainLayout, false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();
        int rc = FFmpeg.execute(cmd);
        return rc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer rc) {
        setClickable(rlMainLayout, true);
        if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            videoCount++;
            path.add(newFile.getPath());
            mediaType.add(Constants.TAG_VIDEO);
            al.add(Uri.fromFile(newFile));
            vehicleNewImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rvProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvProgressPercentage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
            rvProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvProgressPercentage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.oops_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            rvProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvProgressPercentage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.oops_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(rc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library
minSDK 24
Works in latest SDK version
*com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min:6.0-1*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).