# FFmpeg not working on Android version 10(Q)

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, video-compression

I am using FFmpeg for the Video compress & audio video merge & to making the duet with the help of FFmpeg.it's working well on all lower version of Android. but not working on ANDROID 10(Q). it directly goes to on Faiure with empty error meesage.Anysolution relevant to this.Thanx in Advacnce.

Comment: There are many different FFmpeg bindings for Android. It would be helpful if you specified the one with the issue.

Comment: i have mentioned all because i got the issues inall cases. i"l specify with single of merging video with the Audio file.
        outputFilePathAudio = OptiUtils.makeDirectoryAudio()
        outputFileMergeVideo = OptiUtils.makeDirectoryVideo()
        optiVideoEditor = OptiVideoEditor.with(context)

  FFmpeg.getInstance(context).loadBinary(object : FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler {
                override fun onFailure() {
                }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG commands isn't working in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143381/ffmpeg-commands-isnt-working-in-android-q)

Comment: Thanx Vinesh Chauhan its working at my end. Thanx for your reply on my question

Answer (score 2):

I have used belowed version of ffmpeg that increase the conversion speed and works in all android version Displayed in documentation...

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

hope this will work for you..!!!

Comment: Thanx for your Reply.i"l check with this code once is it working well or not. Thankyou soo much.